# Indenting Javascript file line by line?

Tags: javascript, indentation

Is there any way in visual studio 2010 to indent javascript file line by line? I have got a big javascript file where all code is just on one line, so readability of the code is too much compromised.

Any hint? Thanks

Comment: This might help you http://jsbeautifier.org/ (not the direct way, but it's working)

Comment: [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/), [PrettyJs](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/41a0cc2f-eefd-4342-9fa9-3626855ca22a)

Comment: In VS: `Edit` > `Advanced` > either `Format Document` or `Format Selection`.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to copy the entire file content in this site : http://jsbeautifier.org/ then press the Beatify JavaScript or HTML button, and you will get the js properly formated.

Now I suppose that Visual Studio could have a service identical to the sugested one, but I have not used it at all.

The PhpStorm that I am in love with it, has this option, to beautify the code if the code is compressed, as well allows me to define the look of the code format.

Also, as already described by @Andreas, you can use the plugin : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/41a0cc2f-eefd-4342-9fa9-3626855ca22a

Comment: That really helps, Thank you. I was wondering if there is some solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't forget to check what answer was the correct. This way you will help other people from reading an answered question.